# Connecting to mysql database and sending mail

Tags: php, mysqli

so I am using this plugin called user-your-drive for wordpress. And in plugin there is function to send user notification when something is uploaded to drive. Now so far it was made that you can send it to only one user and I am now trying to change it to send it to multiple emails. 
I've got it to work with this code

```
    $mailiBaza = array();
    $mailiBaza[] = "mail1@gmail.com";
    $mailiBaza[] = "mail2@gmail.com";
    $mailiBazaFinal = implode(',', $mailiBaza);
    $recipients = strtr(trim($this->options['notificationemail']), array(

        "%admin_email%" => get_site_option('admin_email'),

        "%user_email%" => $mailiBazaFinal,

        "%linked_user_email%" => $linked_user_email

    ));
```

This indeed sends mail to those 2 mail addresses. But now i want to populate array with emails from my database as there are over 800 mails. I've been using same mysql connection logic for multiple projects now and it works everytime. As soon as I add before $mailiBaza = array();

```
    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

I no longer get any mails anywhere.

Now i am no php expert and I am sure I am missing something but I just have no idea what it could be as code for connecting onto db is always the same. I even tried using different servers and databases...

Comment: [**FYI:**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) You can define your array easily by doing `$arr = [ 'email1', 'email2' ]` in PHP 5.4 and above.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your emails as  `$mailiBaza[] = "mail1@gmail.com";`, there is no comma separing them. Just loop through the array and send to everybody.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($mailiBaza);$i++)
    {//mail}
```

Comment: Sending mail works.. But only to ones I add manually like this
    $mailiBaza[] = "mail1@gmail.com";
    $mailiBaza[] = "mail2@gmail.com";
I want to populate $mailiBaza from by database and soon as i add the code to connect to mysqli everything stops working

Comment: There may be too many and they are getting blocked by spam filter on your host's server? Check with them.

Comment: If you are asking someone to write the code which selects the emails and sends the emails then I suggest you take the [tour]. If you have a specific issue, feel free to ask.

Comment: @ClaudiusDan I dont even get to the part where i select the mails.. It stops working as soon as i try to connect to db

Comment: Syntax looks alright from my POV, database's details are 100% correct?

Answer (score 0):

I cant say what was wrong but now I put mysqli connecting and selecting to another .php file and included it into this original one and now it works.